# PDO и json. Как сделать всё в один массив?

Tags: php, json, pdo

Есть код, который выводит данные из таблицы `servers`:

```
include 'mysql.php';

if ($_GET['id'] != "") {
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ownerid` = '{$_GET['id']}'") as $row) {
        $servers = $row['ServerName'];
        $array = array("Servers" => ["$servers"]);
        $json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $json;
    }
}
```

При выполнении которого выводится следующее:

```
{"Servers":["ServerName1"]}{"Servers":["ServerName2"]}
```

Я хочу, чтобы у меня это выводилось так:

```
{"Servers":["ServerName1","ServerName2"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее так должно сработать. Вначале, перед циклом, мы задаём пустой массив с ключом `Servers`, в цикле пробегаемся по элементам из ответа и заполняем этот пустой массив, после чего выводим **вне** цикла результат.

```
include 'mysql.php';

if ($_GET['id'] != "") {
    $servers['Servers'] = [];
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ownerid` = '{$_GET['id']}'") as $row) {
        $servers['Servers'][] = $row['ServerName'];
    }
    $json = json_encode($servers, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!